# Find a counter example

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

> The interior of the union is the union of the interiors.  $\text{int}\left(A\cup B\right) = \text{int}(A) \cup \text{int}(B)$

I'm not too sure about to get started with this one.  Any hints so as to help me to understand what I need to do?

**Attempt**

$A=[a,b)$

$B=[c,d)$

If I just do a normal union I get this:

$[a,b)\cup[c,d)=\{a,c\}$

If I take the interior union of the sets I get:

$\text{int} A=(a,b)$

$\text{int} B=(c,d)$

And so:

$\text{int} A \cup \text{int} B = \{0\}$

However, if I do the following:

$\text{int} (A \cup B)$

I get $(a,c)$

Comment: Consider two adjoining sets where the shared boundary is in the interior of the union

Comment: For example a non-trivial $A$ whose closure is not equal to its interior, and its complement

Comment: How do you get $(a,b)\cup(c,d)=\emptyset$????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're asking for a hint, I suggest trying to find intervals $A$ and $B$ as counter examples.

More hints:

> $A=[0,1), B = [1,2]$

Comment: OK I just attempted a counter example, I'll update my question.  Please let me know if I'm on the right track

Comment: OK it's updated, let me know.  I'm sure it could be wayyyy off.

Comment: @free_mind It's pretty way way off. $[a,b)\cup [c,d)=\{a,c\}$ is very not true. For example, if $a=c=0, b=d=1$, then the union is $[0,1)$, not $\{0,0\}$...

Comment: @5xum why is that not true?  (I'm not doubting that it's not true, I just don't understand)

Comment: @free_mind Because $\{a,c\}$ is a set containing only two elements ($a$ and $c$), while the union of two intervals can contain infinitely many intervals...

Comment: @5xum I see.  So it should be (a,c)

Comment: @free_mind Then it is still wrong. Is the union of $[0,1)$ and $[10,11)$ equal to $(0,10)$?

Comment: @5xum no.  I see what you're getting at.  Because I would have values between $0$ and $1$ and $10$ and $11$.

Comment: @free_mind There you go. Keep trying to find a counterexample! By the way, you don't need to go abstract and keep values $a,b,c,d$ as free variables. Try it with some concrete values of the numbers!

Comment: @5xum thanks so much for your help!  I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

One has $\text{int}A\subset A\subset A\cup B$ and $\text{int}B\subset B\subset A\cup B$ and so $\text{int}A\cup\text{int}B\subset A\cup B$. The interior of $A\cup B$ is the largest open contained in $A\cup B$ and $\text{int}A\cup\text{int}B$ is open as the Union of two interiors ie two open sets and so

$$\text{int}A\cup\text{int}B\subset\text{int}(A\cup B)$$

In $\Bbb{R}$ consider $A=[0,1)$ and $B=[1,2]$. We have $\text{int}(A\cup B)=(0,2)$ and $\text{int}A\cup\text{int}B=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$

Answer (score 1):

Another nice counter example:

If singletons are closed sets in your space (which they usually are) and if they are not open sets (which, except for discreet topologies, they are), you can take

$$A=\{x_0\}\\ B=X\setminus \{x_0\}$$

in which case $B$ is open (so it is its own interior), and $A$ is not open (and has an empty interior), so

$$\text{int}(A)\cup \text{int}(B) = \emptyset\cup B=B\neq X =\text{int}(A\cup B)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $D\subseteq X$ is dense and $D^c$ is dense as well then  $\text{int}D=\varnothing=\text{int}D^c$ and $\text{int}D\cup D^c=\text{int}X=X$.

Example: $D=\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R$.